# How run php file and other language in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

How run php,java script,asp,html,css file in the wordpress cms?

similar w3school.com

http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress is a CMS written in PHP, that is the server-side language used. HTML/CSS/Javascript will all work nicely with PHP (you can put all three directly into your .PHP files and they will be rendered).

ASP is a different server-side language, picking one or the other for your project is probably a good idea. (Also, I don't think w3schools is running Wordpress, it is their own ASP code)

Comment: If you have questions about the differences between ASP and PHP or which would be better for your particular project, I'd be happy to help. If my answer was helpful to you please "accept" it! Have a nice day.

Comment: Is there a wordpress plugin for run php file?

Comment: Wordpress IS php files, the entire Wordpress codebase is written in PHP. If you look inside the Wordpress directory, you can see all the PHP files that make up the CMS. You are welcome to modify the Wordpress PHP code to suite your needs.

Comment: no. I know w3school don use wordpress that's coding with asp. // But I want run asp in wordpress .. is free service to display asp similar this site?http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php